# focusout and click both triggering callback

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I want a dropdown to close whenever a user tabs away from it. For that I am using the focusout event.

```
menu.addEventListener('focusout', function (event) {
    if (event.relatedTarget === null || !event.relatedTarget.matches('[data-dropdown-item]')) {
        closeDropdown(this.parentElement.querySelector('[data-dropdown]'));
    }   else {
        return;
    }
});
```

I have a click event listener on a button to open or close the dropdown. Because when you click the button you are also focusing away from the dropdown, both the focusout and the click event handler are firing, so the menu closes and then instantly opens again when the button is clicked.

```
function openOrCloseDropdown(button) {
    if (button.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'false') {
        openDropdown(button);
    }   else if (button.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true') {
        closeDropdown(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get as event target and relatedTarget then in those cases when you click the button?

Comment: As expected, the relatedTarget is the button that open/closes the dropdown, the event target it whichever link inside the dropdown that had focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `!document.activeElement` inside a keyup eventListener works:

```
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        if (!document.activeElement.matches('[data-dropdown-item]')) {
            dropdownButtons.forEach(button => {
                closeDropdown(button);
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could "mute" the click handler of the button if it is the related target of the `focusout` event;

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
    button = document.getElementById('button');

menu.addEventListener('focusout', function (event) {
  menu.className = 'inactive';
  if(event.relatedTarget === button) {
    event.relatedTarget.setAttribute("data-muted", true);
  }
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(menu.className === 'active'){
    menu.className = 'inactive';
  } 
  else if(!this.getAttribute('data-muted')) {
    menu.className = 'active';
  }
  
  this.removeAttribute('data-muted');
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="inactive" id="menu" tabindex="1" style="float: left;">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
</ul>

<button id="button" style="float: right;">Menu</button>
```

Comment: A bit buggy? In what way? Click button, menu appears. Click again, menu disappears. Click on menu while it's showing and either click off it, or click button to hide it. So what's "buggy"?

Comment: @o-t-w I didn't make an actual menu. I just made it able to gain focus so you could see that it it works. Please explain what is "buggy"